# Truncate and add ... if string is more than x characters

Tags: sql, postgresql

We would like to trunate the string if it is longer than 100 and add `...` at the end.

We would like to do the whole operation on the DB to avoid network cost.

We use `substring(s, 1, 100)` but how we can combine it with a function (most optimal function) to check and add the `...` if the string is more than 100 characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
(case when length(s) < 100 then s
      else substring(s, 1, 97) || '...'
 end)
```